# How to match between two arrays and update one based on criteria

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I'm trying to match two supplier csv's and update one based on the results of the other; things like if price is different, update one file with the matching item of the other. If the product is in the first csv but not in the other, update it. Once the data set is adjusted, I'll write it back to the csv which I'm ok with. Each supplier file is about 9000 lines long. Sample data from the two Puts lines in the code are:

```
#<struct RecordBUY item_type=nil, buy_product_id="1000", product_name="Plastic Jeweled     Crown", product_type=nil, product_code_SKU="105238", option_set=nil, duplicate={"1000"=>["105238"]}, brand_name="Rubies Costumes", prod_desc="This plastic crown has six large jewel stones accross the top.  Adjustable headband. (Colors of the jewel stones may vary, our choice please.)", cost_price="$3.76", prod_weight="00.14", prod_width="5.75", prod_height="0.5", prod_depth="23.5", prod_category="Hats, Wigs & Masks", prod_upn="082686025935", prod_size="One Size", prod_color="Gold">
#<struct BCRecord item_type="Product", bc_product_id="620", product_name="Dollar Ring", product_type=nil, product_code_SKU="109624", option_set=nil, duplicate=nil, brand_name="Rubies Costumes", prod_desc="Ring has three large glittery Dollar Signs '$'  that extend over your fingers.", cost_price="3.20", prod_weight="0.7200", prod_width="4.0000", prod_height="1.0000", prod_depth="7.0000", prod_category="Accessories & Makeup", prod_upn="82686006996", prod_size=nil, prod_color=nil, option_set=nil, price="5.60", allow_purchases=[21]>
```

I read the csv data into arrays against respective objects, but don't know how to do searching and updating efficiently. I did not come across concepts to avoid the bad ones (or whether doing a bad one on 9k lines is actually bad or just frowned upon). What I have is:

```
puts records[0]
puts recordsBC[1]

#start script
records.each do | buyline |
  recordsBC.each do | bcline |
    if bcline.product_code_SKU == buyline.product_code_SKU
      ##update pricing (brute force);
      #bcline.price = buyline.cost_price * 1.75 #this fails with undefined method `price=' for #<Record:0x007fbb9088b960> 
      bcline.cost_price = buyline.cost_price
    end

    ##if product is in BC currently, but not in buy - needs to be marked as inactive in BC
    if bcline.product_code_SKU.include? buyline.product_code_SKU
      #bcline.allow_purchases = "N" # this fails with undefined method `allow_purchases=' for #<Record:0x007fb2878822c8> 
    end
    #if product is in Buy but not in BC then add it into BC
    if buyline.product_code_SKU.include? bcline.product_code_SKU
      recordsBC.push buyline
    end
  end
end
```

I can't figure out a better way, nor understand why I'm getting the undefined method errors on some but not all lines. I'm not after complete answers, just enough to figure out the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by reducing the number of iterations. At the moment you are iterating through all of recordsBC for each buyline. So I'd start with:

```
records.each do | buyline |
  record_subset = recordsBC.select{|r|!(r.product_code_SKU.split & buyling.product_code_SKU.split).empty?}

  record_subset.each do |bcline|
  .....

  end
end
```

That should mean you only iterate through bcline items that have a matching product_code_SKU. You may have to modify the split as your example doesn't show how multiple SKUs are separated (e.g. '123 456', '123,456', or '123/456')

Comment: Thanks ReggieB - looking into that now.  I don't think the split is required as the SKU is always a single number? Also - why use a binary & rather than logical? Speed? (and will a binary & operate correctly on single number SKU's?)

Comment: I used a logical & because I wanted the result to be the elements that were in both arrays. [1,2,3] & [3,4,5] = [3]. If you use a logical 'and' you are basically saying 'do this and if this returns truth do that'. So [1,2,3] and [3,4,5] = [3,4,5] because in ruby [1,2,3] is not false nor nil so behaves as true, and the the second statement returns [3,4,5]. [1,2,3] && [3,4,5] has the same result (but && takes presidence: so (true and true or false and false) = false but (true && true or false && false) = true.